# Does Stack Overflow use Google Adsense again?

Tags: discussion, advertising

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236426/362477, Stack Overflow has stopped displaying Google Adsense a few years back.

But today I saw your advertisements are redirected to Google Ads... Please see the screenshot.

Alternately I have this question too: Why does Stack Overflow link to their own pages using Google Ads, instead of just linking?

[image]

Comment: That post you linked refers to those annoying four-text-link ad boxes that would display ads to random unrelated sites, usually based on a combination of past browsing history and page content. Very different service that we would never use again.

Comment: SE switched back to Google ads in October 2017...see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1

Comment: @gparyani reads like an answer to me! You can't dupe close across meta sites after all and it annoyingly won't end up in the sidebar as a related page.

Comment: Enough info to allow the OP to complete the Q+A he started.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I didn't understand what you said

Answer (score 8):

I'm a dev on the Ad Server Team here, and AFAIK we don't use AdSense.

We **do** use DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) which is an AdServer.  So we use that to serve up our own ads.  And I believe that we route links through DFP for click-tracking.

Also, they just renamed [DFP to Google Ad Manager](https://www.blog.google/products/admanager/introducing-google-ad-manager/)